# Fused eidolon Synthesist weapon evolution

Tags: pathfinder-1e

A Fused eidolon does not have feats or skills of it's own. However if it had a martial weapon evolution with a bow, would the summoner/eidolon fused be able to use that weapon, or since the summoner controls all the eidolons actions is this evolution unavailiable to synthesists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL/DR:** Fused Synthesist Summoner is proficient with martial weapons when an eidolon has Weapon Training[martial]

As written, only ability's fluff text mentions the summoner and eidolon as separate entities.

Ability [Fuse Eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo---summoner-archetypes/synthesist#TOC-Fused-Eidolon) has a following wording in it's description:

> While fused with his eidolon, the synthesist uses the eidolon’s physical ability scores ... The synthesist gains the eidolon’s hit points as temporary hit points. The synthesist uses the eidolon’s base attack bonus ...

The mechanical wording of the ability specifically modifies only summoner's characteristics and gives him temporary hitpoints losing which will eliminate these modifications. There are no restrictions whatsoever on what is available to eidolon.

> The synthesist uses the eidolon’s base attack bonus, and gains the eidolon’s armor and natural armor bonuses and modifiers to ability scores. **The synthesist also gains access to the eidolon’s special abilities and the eidolon’s evolutions.**

To me, it means that the summoner himself can receive any benefit an evolution could give to an eidolon. It's not even exclusive to synthesists, since [Aspect](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner#TOC-Aspect-Su-) can do that for basic Summoners.

In the evolution's description, you just replace *eidolon* with *fused synthesist*:

[Weapon Training(Ex)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons#TOC-Weapon-Training-Ex-)

> An (synthesist summoner while fused) learns to use a weapon, gaining Simple Weapon Proficiency as a bonus feat. If 2 additional evolution points are spent, it gains proficiency with all martial weapons as well.